# Where does this hose connect on my Chinese Honda SDH125-51?

Tags: honda, motorcycle, part-identification

I have a maintenance question for my Honda motorcycle.
I believe it is a CB125F in most of the world.
I am new to doing my own work and I am trying to identify a hose (pictures attached).

---

### Can you tell me what this hose is, and - most importantly -  is it supposed to connect somewhere at the top?

What I have is a Chinese Honda "CBF125", which is **not a cbf125 in other countries**.

[image]

It's a great, simple carbureted bike that seems to be

- **very close to a CB125E/F**

for most places.

What I am stuck on is the hose in the next two pictures:

[image]

[image]

I was putting things back together for the first time and saw it.
It runs down to this round box and we see the connection in the next 2 pictures.

[image]

[image]

Here's one last shot of the round box from front to back.

[image]

Comment: Does the gas tank have a on/off/reserve switch on it? That looks like it's about in the right location to connect to it. Often, carbureted motorcycles have a vacuum operated fuel valve which will open when vacuum is applied and allow fuel to flow. That way when the motorcycle isn't running, gas won't be able to flow through the carburetors and flood the engine. The round canister might be a vacuum reservoir, which will hold vacuum whenever the engine is running.

Comment: Looks like a vent to me.  Battery vent?

Comment: @DavidWatson, I don't think it could be a battery overflow tube because it goes into a vacuum box, and because the battery is below and behind it.

Comment: @the_storyteller  That's a fair assessment. It just doesn't look like a fuel line to me.  Then again, I don't see anything else resembling a fuel line either lol.

Comment: @DavidWatson - not a fuel line. A vacuum line which runs to a fuel control valve.

Comment: Good morning from China.  :)   It's definitely not the fuel line;  this bike has the nice valve "petcock" coming down from the tank, on the left side.  The fuel line is out of view over there.

Comment: Also not connected to the battery, no.  Definitely the round box behind it.  That round box has a bunch of tubes, connected to most everything.

Comment: Maybe I'll take some more pictures and open another question for "what is the round box".  It certainly is relevant and it's quite new to me.  I know generally to look at fuel, air, spark...  and now this is something else.

Comment: "What is the round box?"  question opened  :)  ...  https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/65556/what-is-this-well-connected-round-box-on-my-chinese-honda-sdh125-51

Comment: After a lot of internet-ting about the round box, I'm getting largely confident of an answer.  I will write it but not mark it Accepted yet, looking for feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's almost certainly your fuel tank evap / "breather" line**

The round box is your "evap can" -- vapor management can that traps and releases polluting vapors through absorption and evaporation.
[The paired question here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/65556/what-is-this-well-connected-round-box-on-my-chinese-honda-sdh125-51) directly addresses identifying the can.

A fuel tank vent or "breather" line is essential to this.  Holding fuel vapor from the tank is maybe the biggest goal of this system.
If all the other hoses from the can are connected and none to the fuel tank, then we should definitely be looking for a fuel tank hose, and that one is going right up there.

- **Look for a matching connection on the back or bottom of the fuel tank
  and that's almost certainly where it's going.**

(of course, make your own decision at your own risk, etc)

It may be something like this:

[image]

Comment: I welcome feedback since I'm new at all this.  If you disagree, please share some more ideas :-)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a breather tube. If so, it shouldn't attach to anything on the top side. It would be set up high so you could possibly ride your bike through deeper water and not get water into your crankcase while doing so.

Comment: I don't think this is a crank case breather. It's too small, and the crank case breathers on Honda bikes I've worked on runs from the crank into the intake before the carburetors. Also, we can see a suspiciously crank-case-breather-ish hose in one of the images, in the correct spot. Also, it doesn't connect to the crank case...

Comment: @the_storyteller - You may be correct about the crankcase part of it, however, it still looks like a breather hose, which wouldn't be attached to anything on the top side. Also, there's no clamp or even clamp marks at the top of the hose, which leads me to believe it's never been attached to anything, lending credence to the breather theory.

Comment: @Paulster2 - I thought some kind of vent hose as well, since it looks like the inside of the hose has the same color dust as the outside.

Comment: @DavidWatson I was also first thinking it hasn't been connected because it is so dirty.  But I'm curious about it because, indeed, that just doesn't seem quite right.   Yes, there's no hose clamp on it,  but I didn't find any sort of holding clamp nearby to keep it as a vent, and Honda is pretty careful.   But then there is some extra rubber around it as though it maybe _was_ in a guide or clamp somewhere...

Comment: To ask an important if embarrassing question ---   when we say connected to the crankcase, what is the crankcase?  (then I could confirm or deny such connection)

Comment: @MikeM - I should update my answer a little ... the crankcase is the part which holds the oil ... where the crankshaft is at. After looking at the images again and what David Watson stated, what you're showing is not the crankcase, but I still believe the tube is some sort of breather.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  --  Sure.   Yes, it's not connected to the core, metal body of the engine-transmission unibody.  I'm highly confident it's that round plastic box.  Maybe I should brush some dirt off it :-D

Comment: So the question raised by @the_storyteller, in the first comment, is the big one we might ask.  What is it the breather for, and are we sure that isn't accounted for?  (in full disclosure, there is another good suggestion (elsewhere) that it is a breather for something, but then it does need to be connected...  so I hope to compare the ideas)

Comment: Have you checked that the tube doesn't connect to a valve on the bottom of the gas tank? If there is no valve, then you should just put the gas tank mostly in place, start the bike, and see if the tube has vacuum or pressure in it. If it has vacuum, then it probably needs to be connected to something. If it has pressure, or no pressure difference, then it is probably okay being left open.

Comment: @the_storyteller Yeah, that's the other theory :)  I don't know about valve, but there is a little pipe. I'm at least temporarily deciding that the box is an evap can, and it definitely wants a fuel tank connection.